# Python: Best data-construct for J.A.R.V.I.S

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, speech-recognition

I'm trying to create an 'AI' (not really) in Python. Therefore I use the SpeechRecognition module to recognize my spoken words and audioplayer modules etc.
All is working fine but now I want to create a clear and classifiable data construct that contains all knowledge of my program. 'Classifiable' means that you can use 'folders and subfolders' for each topic or different areas with different possibilities of words.

To make it a bit clearer here's how I imagine it:

Example 1:

```
class greeting:
    cheerful = {"Hi, how are you?": ["I'm fine!", "Hey nice to see you"],
                "Hey": "Oh hello!"}
    notHappy = {"Hi": "Leave me alone!"}
class topics:
    class football:
        games = {"Did you hear about Manchester?": "Blablabla"}
```

Depending on in which topic/variable the program is (fe. greeting.cheerful) there are different possibilities what you can say.

Example 2: not my favourite

```
brain = {"greeting": {"cheerful": {"Hi, how are you?": ["I'm fine!", "Hey nice to see you"],
            "Hey": "Oh hello!"},
         "notHappy": {"Hi": "Leave me alone!"}},
         "topics": {"football": .................
```

This are just examples I don't know whats the best way for this. After each sentence you say it jumps to another topic where you can continue.

Thanks for you help! Just a little project :)

Greetings

PS: sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 0):

The best structure to date is neural network (not surprisingly). For details you can check something like

https://github.com/voicy-ai/DialogStateTracking